# Espresso: avoid AmbiguousViewMatcherException by specifying the parent view

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, matcher, instrumented-test

`onView(withId(R.id.feeding_name)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` causes AmbiguousViewMatcherException.

Due to multiple fragments on the screen the id "feeding_name" matches multiple views.

I am wondering, if there is any way to specify the parent of the view so that I could do something like `onView(withIdAndParentId(R.id.feeding_name, R.id.fragment_show_feeding)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

Comment: You could try `allOf`, like `onView(allOf(withId(R.id.feeding_name), withParent(withId(R.id.fragment_show_feeding)))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! Make it an official answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try combination of matchers with `allOf`, like for example:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.feeding_name), withParent(withId(R.id.fragment_show_feeding))))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```